# How the wordpress login and signup in react native app

Tags: login, rest-api, plugin-json-api, signup

Can anyone help me to login and sign up in reactnative app
i have a Wordpress website and i want to link my wordpress site to reactnative app.
search lots of solution but no one help me. i am using jwt auth plugin but don't know how to integrate this in reactapp.?

```
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Alert,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  Linking
} from 'react-native'; 
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Remote debugger']);

const userInfo = {username:'demo',password:'demo'};
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };
    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );
        this.state = {
            username:'',
            password:''
        }
    }
    _onPressButton() {
        Alert.alert('Login','Social login');
      }
    _signin = async()=> {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('logged', '1');
        if( userInfo.username===this.state.username && userInfo.password===this.state.password) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
        }
        else {
            alert('Username / Password Incorrect');
        }
    }
    _retrieveData = async () => {
        const logged = await AsyncStorage.getItem('logged'); 
        this.props.navigation.navigate( logged !== '1' ? 'Auth' : 'App' );
    }
  render() {
  const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <>
     <StatusBar backgroundColor="#22a86d" barStyle="light-content" /> 
    <ImageBackground source={require('./images/login_background.png')} style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <View style={styles.body}>
         <Image
          style={{width:230, height: 80,marginBottom:30,resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('./images/logo.png')}
        />

       <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="User Name"
        placeholderTextColor="#fff"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChangeText={(username)=>this.setState({username})}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Password"
        placeholderTextColor="#fff"
        value={this.state.password}
        onChangeText={(password)=>this.setState({password})}
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />

      <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>


       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn} activeOpacity={0.9} 
        onPress={this._signin}>
        <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>Login</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Text style={styles.account}>Don't have an account? 
        <Text style={styles.bold} onPress={() => navigate('Profile')}> Create Account</Text>
      </Text>

      <Text style={styles.signUp}>Signup with</Text>

      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',marginTop:20}}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} 
         onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        <Image
          style={{width:70, height: 60, resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('./images/fb.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} 
         onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        <Image
          style={{width:70, height: 60,resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('./images/twitter.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} 
         onPress={this._onPressButton}>
        <Image
          style={{width:70, height: 60,resizeMode: 'contain'}}
          source={require('./images/google.png')}
        />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View>
   </ImageBackground>
    </>
  );
};
}
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
  Dashboard: {screen: DashboardScreen},
  CampaignList: {screen: CampaignScreen},
  DonorList: {screen:DonorScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: Try this [ User Login With WordPress using React Native](http://carlofontanos.com/user-login-with-wordpress-using-react-native/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Axios to make Post Request to WordPress. There is only one way to connect with WordPress is API you should create a Post request to Wordpress like this

axios.post('http://your-wordpress-website/api/',()=>{

})

Comment: I'm not sure that's a very useful example: it doesn't show the correct login endpoint, or how to pass the username and password, or how to handle the success and fail responses, save the JWT token and pass it to future requests etc.

Comment: You have to pass JWT Token in the header for future requests. for endpoints, you can install a plugins in WordPress or you can create custom endpoints in WordPress